# CSS insert pseudo element in table and move it to the left/right out of parents bounds

Tags: angular, css, sass, pseudo-element

I am using the data-table library "ag-grid" (with Angular 2 but it doesn't matter) and it marks a selected row (default class `.ag-row`) by putting a `.ag-row-selected`class on it. inside a row are a bunch of cells with the `.ag-cell`-class.

Now what I am trying to accomplish is to make a selection not by coloring the background, but by marking the row on the left and right side with a "stripe". I can accomplish this by inserting an empty column at the beginning and the end of the table and then do:

```
$selection-padding-width: 6px;
ag-grid-angular {
  height: 100%;
  // making room for selection-padding-stripe:
  width: calc(100% - 2 * #{$selection-padding-width});
}
/deep/ .ag-row-selected:before {
  height: 25px;
  width: $selection-padding-width;
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: $cyan;
  transform: translateX(-1px);
}
```

The result you can see here: 
[image]

However, when I move the blue stripe from the position of the leftmost cell to the empty area on the left, it disappears, because that empty area is beyond the bounds of the container (see `width: calc(100% - 2 * #{$selection-padding-width});`). I would like to know if there is any way to make the selection-padding (blue stripe) appear above the container, eg be visible when you apply `transform: translateX(-6px)` to it.

If you want to see ag-grid in action, here is a plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ehKrzYNuZ64CYBOClbL6?p=preview

Comment: You want a blue stripe at the beginning and end of a selected row? You could just target the first and last div of each row and give them a border?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when I move the position of the column, the stripes moves too. so I have to call a repaint-method, causing the whole grid to flicker for a short moment

Comment: But I might try adding a border on the whole row.... I will tell you if I run into any problem

Comment: Ok, adding a border on the row was the best solution. I will post an answer later. Thank you ovokuro

Answer (score 0):

Ok as ovokuro suggested in the comment, the best way to deal with this is using a border. But I would recommend using it on the row, not on the cell, because when you move the cell the border moves too with that cell instead of staying on the left or right of the entire row. In the end, my solution looks something like this:

```
/deep/ .ag-header-row {
  background-color: $table-header-color;
  border-left: $selection-padding-width solid $table-header-color;
  border-right: $selection-padding-width solid $table-header-color;
}

/deep/ .ag-row-even:not(.ag-row-selected) {
  border-left: $selection-padding-width solid $even-row-color;
  border-right: $selection-padding-width solid $even-row-color;
}

/deep/ .ag-row-odd:not(.ag-row-selected) {
  border-left: $selection-padding-width solid $odd-row-color;
  border-right: $selection-padding-width solid $odd-row-color;
}

/deep/ .ag-row-selected {
  border-left: $selection-padding-width solid $cyan;
  border-right: $selection-padding-width solid $cyan;
}

/deep/ .ag-row-even, .ag-row-even.ag-row-selected {
  background-color: $even-row-color!important;
}

/deep/ .ag-row-odd, .ag-row-odd.ag-row-selected {
  background-color: $odd-row-colort!important;
}

/deep/ .ag-header-container {
  left: 0!important;
}

/deep/ .ag-body-viewport {
  overflow-x: hidden!important;
}
```

the last two parts are needed to prevent the header and the body from overflowing because ag-grid automatically adds some spacing when you move a column to the rightmost position and there is a border-attribute on the rows. the `!important` is needed because ag-grid adds some classes programmatically that set the same attributes